# Why is my device driver not printing what I input

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
static ssize_t my_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf, size_t
      len, loff_t *off)
{
    static int first=1;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: read()\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Value of loff_t %ld",*off);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside value of stringlength is %d",strlen(buffer));


    if (copy_to_user(buf,buffer, 1) != 0)
        return -EFAULT;
    else
    {
        if(first<=strlen(buffer))
        {   
            first=first+1;
            printk(KERN_INFO "INside value of first is %d",first);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Inside value of stringlength is %d",strlen(buffer));

            return 1;
        }
        else 
              return 0;
    }


    }
      static ssize_t my_write(struct file *f, const char __user *buf,
      size_t len, loff_t *off)
    {
       printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: write()\n");
       if (copy_from_user(buffer, buf+len-1, 1) != 0)
            return -EFAULT;
       else
            return len;

    }
```

However the first time I do echo -n "HEllo" and `cat /dev/mynull`, it prints only `o` and releases the device for some reason.Subsequent `cat /dev/mynull` returns nothing. The value of `strlen(buffer)` is 1.
Why is this happening? THe expected result is that Hello should be printed and `strlen()` should return `5`.

Comment: You should really improve your code formating. It is hard to read. My edit was focused on the retag.

Comment: Are you seeing the other prints, it's just the length that's wrong? Also, how many blocks of code are there here? It is supposed to be just one, because your curly brackets don't line up...

Comment: I guess the blocks line up now. After changing the value to len as suggested by @rodrigo, I get the o printed five time instead of Hello being printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in `my_write`:

```
copy_from_user(buffer, buf+len-1, 1)
```

copies 1 char from the `buf+len-1` user address to the kernel buffer. That is the last char of the user string, that is, the `'o'`. I think it should be:

```
copy_from_user(buffer, buf, len);
```

And then:

```
buffer[len] = 0;
```

just in case the user buffer is not NUL terminated.

All of that without taking into account the `off` value, but that would depend on what exactly you want to do (maybe copy to `buffer + *off`?).
BTW, you should also check for buffers overruns and the like.

Comment: I completely missed that. But even after changing that to len and changing copy_to_user(buf,buffer,strlen(buffer)), it prints o five time instead of Hello being printed.

Comment: Okay finally got it to work. I had to retrun 5 if it was the first time , else I had to return strlen(buffer). Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, accessing directly a user buffer is forbidden, that's why there is a `copy_from_user` function in the first place, instead of just `memcpy`. So you must not use `strlen` this way. That is even without taking into account that the user data may very well not have the ending NUL.

Comment: Buffer is a variable which I have declared in my code and not the user buffer being passed. To use strlen of this is okay beacuse I have set buffer[len]='\0'. Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @user1667307: Ah, you are right in that, it should not be  a problem.